# Using VSCode DevContainers with Dapr - Can't run Dapr Init within postStartCommand because Docker Runtime is not available

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer, docker-in-docker, dapr, devcontainer

I am trying to setup a DevContainer for Dapr to make dev environment setup easy. I would like to run Dapr Init automatically so that there are no manual steps needed to run services.

I put "dapr init" in the postStartCommand, but when it runs it says there is no Docker Runtime available.

```
❌  could not connect to docker. docker may not be installed or running
```

Immediately after that fails, I can manually run "dapr init" in a terminal and it works appropriately.

I have tried giving it more time by adding a "sleep 30", but that doesn't seem to help.

Is there anything I can do to ensure the docker runtime is up and running so I can automatically initialize dapr?

Here is my devcontainer definition

```
{
  "name": "Dapr Quickstarts Codespace",
  "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "extensions": [
        "golang.go",
        "ms-azuretools.vscode-dapr",
        "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
        "ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools",
        "ms-dotnettools.csdevkit"
      ]
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/dapr/cli/dapr-cli:0": {},
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-in-docker:2": {}
    },
  "mounts": [
    // Mount docker-in-docker library volume
    "source=codespaces-linux-var-lib-docker,target=/var/lib/docker,type=volume"
  ],
  "postStartCommand": "dapr init",
  // Always run image-defined docker-init.sh to enable docker-in-docker
  "overrideCommand": false,
  "remoteUser": "codespace",
  "runArgs": [
    // Enable ptrace-based debugging for Go in container
    "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
    "--security-opt",
    "seccomp=unconfined",

    // Enable docker-in-docker configuration
    "--init",
    "--privileged"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which devcontainer are you using? I'm trying to use the "Dapr with C#" container and it fails to start due to certificate error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [`dapr init` command](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/cli/dapr-init/) does [rely on Docker](https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/install-dapr-selfhost/), which apparently has not fully initialized when `postStartCommand` is executed, you might consider, as a workaround, a script that checks for Docker availability *before* running the `dapr init` command

Create a file named `check-docker.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Wait for Docker
until docker info >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "Waiting for Docker..."
    sleep 1
done

# Now run dapr init
dapr init
```

And update your [`devcontainer.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container) to point to the `check-docker.sh` script in the `postStartCommand` field:

```json
"postStartCommand": "/path/to/check-docker.sh",
```

---

> Does this actually work, though? I've added a 3-minute sleep and after the sleep docker is still not initialized. I suspect it simply will not initialize until the `postStartCommand` is finished executing.

That would mean the `postStartCommand` execution may be blocking the Docker initialization process.
That makes sense, especially if the Docker service is being initialized in the same context or process tree as the `postStartCommand`. In that case, the `postStartCommand` would block Docker from fully initializing until it completes.

A possible solution could be to offload the `dapr init` command to a background process, which would allow `postStartCommand` to complete, and Docker to continue its initialization. That could be achieved by updating the script to run `dapr init` in the background or after a delay, allowing the `postStartCommand` to complete, and potentially allowing Docker to finish initializing.

The `check-docker.sh` script, which now offloads `dapr init` to a background process, would be (using "[`nohup`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/7490)"):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Function to check docker and run dapr init
run_dapr_init() {
  # Wait for Docker
  until docker info >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "Waiting for Docker..."
    sleep 1
  done

  # Now run dapr init
  dapr init
}

# Export the function and run it in the background
export -f run_dapr_init
nohup bash -c run_dapr_init &

# Exit immediately so postStartCommand completes
exit 0
```

And the updated `postStartCommand` in your `devcontainer.json` would remain the same:

```json
"postStartCommand": "/path/to/check-docker.sh",
```

The `postStartCommand` should complete immediately, potentially allowing Docker to finish initializing, while the `dapr init` command will be attempted in a separate background process.

If you place `check-docker.sh` at the root of your project, the path would just be `"/check-docker.sh"`.

Comment: Does this actually work though? I've added a 3 minute sleep and after the sleep docker is still not initialized. I suspect it simply will not initialize untiil the postStartCommand is finished executing.

Comment: @Josh OK. I have updated the answer to propose a possible solution.

Comment: After some testing, looks like I was wrong about the blocking and it just needed enough time on the main thread, but the loop definitely helped with that so thanks!

Comment: @Josh Great, well done!